# Dynamic sounds in Monogame

Tags: c#, mono, monogame

How can I create dynamic sounds in Monogame? In XNA you can use DynamicSoundEffectInstance or SoundEffect.FromStream but the former is currently under development, and the latter seems to not be implemented at all.

Comment: It's possible that it's not implemented yet. Maybe you can be the one to implement it.

Comment: I would, but I don't even know the library they're using (might be OpenGL and OpenAL)... Maybe I'll do some digging and hacking. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The MonoGame documentation suggests dynamically generated sounds can be achieved using: [DynamicSoundEffectInstance](https://docs.monogame.net/api/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.DynamicSoundEffectInstance.html)

Its been a few years since I've tried - but I managed to get a C64 SID emulator pumping data into that, and deployed it to my phone!

Happy programming.